# sql joining table, not providing perfect result

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql

let me explain what i need, i have 2 table named A and B. B is sub table for A.

Here is Schema:

```
------------------------
Table B:
itemId version qty  AId
44       1      1   200
44       1      2   201
44       2      2   200
------------------------
Table A:
id  tId
200 100
201 100
------------------------
```

and here is what i need: i need sum of all latest version qty that have same tId.

here is my query:

```
select sum(qty) as sum from B
left join A on A.id=B.AId
where itemId=44 and tId=100 and 
version=(select max(version) from B where itemId=44 and tId=100)
```

the result get wrong when one item got version 2 and version 1 ignored.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

what exactly i need is:

```
itemId version qty  AId
44       2      2   200
44       1      2   201
```

And Result of Sum(qty) must be 4, because they have same tId and they have Max version in each AId.

Comment: Please give an example of the output that you require

Comment: @RaunakThomas , Thanks for comment. i add it in edit part

Comment: @Khir Please add which dbms you are using in tags.

Comment: I suggest adding a tag for the specific flavour of SQL that you need the answer in.

Comment: @NishantGupta , i add it

Comment: @Richardissimo, sql server , postgresql . i only need the way that solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks, because that rules out the answer I was going to give, which would have worked on `Sql-server`.

Comment: Unrelated but: the condition `and tId=100` in the `where` clause turns your outer join back into an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution

```
select b.* from B as b
inner join 
 (select AID,itemId,Max(version) as mVersion from B 
  group by AID,itemID) d 
on b.AID = d.AID and b.itemID = d.itemID and b.Version = d.mVersion
inner join A as a
on B.AID = a.id
where b.itemID = 44 --apply if you need
```

result

```
itemid  version qty aid
44         2    2   200
44         1    2   201
```

this will give you result as you sum of quantity

```
select itemID,sum(qty) from (
select b.* from B as b
inner join 
 (select AID,itemId,Max(version) as mVersion from B 
  group by AID,itemID) d 
on b.AID = d.AID and b.itemID = d.itemID and b.Version = d.mVersion
inner join A as a
on B.AID = a.id
where b.itemID = 44 --apply if you need 
) e group by itemID
```

result

```
itemid  sum
44       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window function.

```
select itemid, version, qty, aid
from (
  select *, max(version) over (partition by AId) as latestVersion 
  from B
) as B
where version = latestVersion
```

to sum up

```
select tId, SUM(qty) AS qty_sum
from (
  select *, max(version) over (partition by AId) as latestVersion 
  from B
) as B
join A on B.AId = A.id
where version = latestVersion
group by tId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.*
FROM B
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Aid,MAX(version) AS version FROM B WHERE itemId=44 GROUP BY AId) AS B1
ON B.Aid=B1.Aid 
AND B.version=B1.version
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM A WHERE tId=100) AS A
ON A.id=B.Aid
Order BY B.aid
```

**For Sum of qty**

```
SELECT SUM(B.qty)
FROM B
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Aid,MAX(version) AS version FROM B WHERE itemId=44 GROUP BY AId) AS B1
ON B.Aid=B1.Aid AND B.version=B1.version
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM A WHERE tId=100) AS A
ON A.id=B.Aid
GROUP BY A.tid
```

**Output**

```
itemid  version qty aid
44      2       2   200
44      1       2   201
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/092dd/5

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
DECLARE @TA Table (id int,tid int)
DECLARE @TB Table (itemid int, version int,qty int,AID int)

INSERT INTO @TA
SELECT 200, 100
UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 100


INSERT INTO @TB
SELECT 44,1,1,201
UNION ALL
SELECT 44,1,2,200
UNION ALL
SELECT 44,2,3,200
UNION ALL
SELECT 44,2,5,201


DECLARE @tid int
SET @tid = 100

SELECT XB.* FROM @Tb XB INNER JOIN
(SELECT Version,Max(AID) Aid FROM @TA A INNER JOIN @TB B ON A.id = B.AID AND tid = @tid Group By Version) X
ON X.version = XB.version and XB.AID = X.Aid
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this query help you to solve your problem

```
    SELECT itemId, version, qty , AId FROM (
      SELECT itemId, version, qty , AId FROM b 
      LEFT JOIN a ON (b.aid = a.id)
    ) temp
    WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM b WHERE b.aid = temp.aid)
   and temp.tid = 100 and temp.itemId = 44
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems in Postgres are typically using the (proprietary) operator `distinct on ()`

So to get the latest version for each a.id, you can use:

```
select distinct on (a.id) b.*
from a 
  join b on a.id = b.aid
order by a.id, b.version desc;
```

The above returns:

```
itemid | version | qty | aid
-------+---------+-----+----
    44 |       2 |   2 | 200
    44 |       1 |   2 | 201
```

You can then sum over the result:

```
select sum(qty) 
from (
  select distinct on (a.id) b.qty
  from a 
    join b on a.id = b.aid
  order by a.id, b.version desc
) t;
```

Note that normally an `order by` in a derived table is useless, but in this case it's needed because otherwise `distinct on ()` wouldn't work.

Online example: http://rextester.com/DRHK19268